# Does the industrial_extrinsic_cal package support multi cam extrinsic calibration with non-overlapping FOVs?

Tags: ros, multiple, camera-calibration

I know it can do "Multi-Camera Extrinsic Calibration with a Target" as per this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_extrinsic_cal/Tutorials/Multi_camera_calibration), but does it work if none of the cameras have overlapping FOVs?